# Trying to generate date column of excel using xml file. But, facing date format issue

Tags: excel, xml, excel-formula, formatting

```
<Column index="1">
    <Heading></Heading>
    <FieldValue></DataField>
    <Format>Text</Format>
</Column>
```

I am using the xml file which has structure somewhat like above for generating columns of excel file.

Here, I have FieldValue null. That means, I will be entering value here. As I have written the Format as "Text" it should give me Format of column as Text only or if I will use Date as a format, it should show the same. But, with both of these, I got the format as General. That results in changing the date format default to "mm-dd-yyyy".

**Expected output**

- Column format: Text or Date
- Format of date: mm/dd/yyyy

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: To clarify, the difference in what you need is the  -  should be a /  ?